# Converting list comprehension notation into a for loop

Tags: python

I've been seeing many solutions with list comprehensions and i'm wondering if it's possible to convert it into a for loop notation.

For example, if i have a list comprehension notation:

```
radix = [radix_sort(i,0) for i in lst]
```

if i write it in:

```
for i in lst:
   radix_sort(i,0)
```

do i get the same output? What differentiates both? Is it more efficient for list comprehension to be applied rather than conventional for loops?

Comment: Check it out. It's art not a science.

Comment: You should run the code and find out. I'd give it a shot but you didn't post your list, your desired output, or anything useful for that matter.

Comment: Generally a list comprehension is more efficient, but many cases will have no measurable difference.  You should benchmark with your own data, but I wonder why you would want to convert if the list comprehension is working.  When I first saw these I took a while to understand them, but its worth it and now I find myself using them regularly.  Also remember dictionary and set comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension creates a list—that's the whole point of it. But your loop doesn't create anything at all. So no, you're not going to get the same "output".

The equivalent loop is:

```
radix = []
for i in lst:
    radix.append(radix_sort(i,0))
```

The list comprehension is defined to mean almost exactly the same thing as this. It may run a bit faster, at least in CPython,<sup>*</sup> but it will have the same effect.

If that `radix_sort` returns a copy of the list in sorted order, your loop was doing a lot of work for no effect. But now, as with the list comprehension, you're saving the result of all that work.

If, on the other hand, that `radix_sort` sorts the list in-place and returns nothing, then both the list comprehension and the explicit loop with `append` are highly misleading, and you should just use the loop without `append`.

---

<sub>* For example, in a comprehension, you don't have any way to access `radix` until the looping is done, so the compiler can make some assumptions and use a faster way of appending to the list.</sub>